# SQL update query linked to a control

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In the query below, I am trying to take the value identified on a form located in the text box 'txtholding01' and transfer it to the table tbldependencies01 where the ID number located in the ID field of the table is equal to that in the control txtDependencyID.  It seems that the syntax/naming convention where I am trying to retrieve the value located in 'txtholding01' is not working.

```
sql_GET = "UPDATE tbldependencies01 SET DowntimeWaitingNotes = me.txtholding01 WHERE ID=" & txtDependencyID
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (sql_GET)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

off the top of my head this should do the trick:

```
sql_GET = "UPDATE tbldependencies01 SET DowntimeWaitingNotes = " & me.txtholding01.Text & " WHERE ID=" & txtDependencyID
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (sql_GET)
```

however you'd open your code to sql injection attack, you might want to explore that subject. Cheers
JB